# MySQL Truncation Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In one of my tables, I have a column with some null values and some integer values.  When I use MySQL Workbench to set a default value and non-null for that column, I get a truncation error.

When my colleague performs the same operation, his apply works and the null value are set to 0.

The only obvious difference is that he is running MySQL Server 5.6 and I am running 5.5.

An example table can be created with the following CREATE:

```
CREATE  TABLE 'resource`.`test_table` (
`idtest_table` INT NOT NULL ,
`bad_column` BIGINT(20) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`idtest_table`) );
```

Insert some values as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `resource`.`test_table` (`idtest_table`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `resource`.`test_table` (`idtest_table`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `resource`.`test_table` (`idtest_table`) VALUES (3);
```

The command that is failing is:

```
ALTER TABLE `resource`.`test_table` CHANGE COLUMN `bad_column` `bad_column` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  ;
```

with the following error:

```
ERROR 1265: Data truncated for column 'bad_column' at row 1
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `resource`.`test_table` CHANGE COLUMN `bad_column` `bad_column` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1050: Table 'test_table' already exists
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `idtest_table` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bad_column` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtest_table`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Is there a setting in the MySQL config that allows this?  Is it the version?

Comment: Provide the exact DDL query and error message

Comment: Can you post the full error message your getting please and the create statement for the table your having problems altering please?

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring because `bad_columns` has a value of `NULL` after the insert.

You are changing the column type to "not NULL", so what can the database do?  It can generate an error.  The `default` value doesn't apply to existing rows.

If you want to do this, then update the column first:

```
update resource.test_table
    set bad_column = 0
    where bad_column is null;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.  I know how to remedy this problem.  My colleague does not have to perform this extra step - his MySQL automatically does this step.  I am more interested in why we are seeing this strange behavior.

Comment: You can test it on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9).  The error seems to vary by version of MySQL.  Perhaps it worked in an earlier version.